# Is there a tool for python that can visualize methods and classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a tool that can visualize (such as tree view) all python functions and classes in a program and which function calls other functions? Trying to find dependencies of some real messy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is called `pycallgraph`.

Comment: Does pycallgraph run the entire program to create the tree view?